# cutZeros function in python

Tags: python, string

I have to create a string function that removes the leading zeros of a string and then returns  the new string. When I run what I have so far it returns nothing, zilch. I would appreciate if someone could take a look!

```
def cutZeros(string):
    variable=0
    newString=''
    for index in range(len(string)):
        while string[variable]==0:
            string[variable]=''
            newString+= string[variable]
        variable+=1
    return newString
again='y'
while again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
    string=raw_input('Enter your string of digits: ')
    if len(string)>0:
        print cutZeros(string)
    else:
        print 'invalid input'
    again=raw_input ("again? (Y/N): ")
```

Comment: The first error in your code is this: `while string[variable] == '0':`

Comment: Why don't you just use `string.lstrip('0')`? Also, `string[variable]=''` won't work.

Comment: Also `variable` is a **terrible** name for a variable...